# Angular 15 dynamically load component from lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I need to dynamically load an angular component from a lazy loaded module.

Untill Angular 14 I used this code:

```
async onModalOpenButtonClick(modalname: string) {
    const module = await import('../../modals/basic/basic-modals.module');
    const component = await import('../../modals/basic/modal-launch/modal-launch.component');

    const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module.BasicModalsModule);
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);

    const componentFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.ModalLaunchComponent);
    const componentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(
      componentFactory,
      undefined,
      this.injector,
      [],
      moduleRef
    );
    componentRef.instance.openModal(modalname);
  }
```

But on Angular 15 componentFactoryResolver and ViewContainerRef.createComponent are deprecateded.

How I can update my code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the updated code for dynamically loading an Angular component from a lazy loaded module in Angular 15:

```
async onModalOpenButtonClick(modalname: string) {
  // Import the module and component
  const module = await import('../../modals/basic/basic-modals.module');
  const component = await import('../../modals/basic/modal-launch/modal-launch.component');

  // Create a module ref for the lazy loaded module
  const moduleRef = await module.loadModule();

  // Create a component factory for the component
  const componentFactory = await moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

  // Create a component ref for the component
  const componentRef = await this.vcr.createComponent(
    componentFactory,
    undefined,
    this.injector,
    [],
    moduleRef
  );

  // Call the openModal method on the component instance
  componentRef.instance.openModal(modalname);
}
```

The main difference between the old code and the new code is that the `componentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` methods have been deprecated in Angular 15. Instead, you need to use the `loadModule` method to create a module ref for the lazy loaded module, and then use the `componentFactoryResolver` method to resolve the component factory for the component. Finally, you can use the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` method to create a component ref for the component.

I hope this helps